# Can I prevent a Windows batch file from execution through a double-click?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to setup a Windows `.BAT` file in such a way so that it's possible to execute when called from `CMD`, but does not run when someone double-clicks the file?

Comment: Take a look at this [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2728) thread.

Comment: You realize your question title contradicts what you wrote in your description. Your question title should just say "in an interactive session".

Comment: @Squashman I'm not sure what you mean. If launched from `CMD` (interactive), I want it to run. If launched from a double-click (non-interactive), I want to prevent it from running. I see no contradiction.

Comment: Your understanding of the terminology is backward.  Double clicking the batch file would be Interactive.  Running from a console is normally considered non-interactive because a console program can run without a user logged in.

Comment: I'll modify the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The environment variable `%cmdcmdline%` contains the command line used to launch CMD.exe.  If a batch file was launched from a click in Explorer or on the Desktop, it will be:

```
C:\Path\To\cmd.exe /c ""c:\path\to\batch\file.bat" "
```

The full path to the batch file can also be accessed as `%~f0` within the batch file itself to compare with that variable.

Comment: I get this when I click: `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\BatchFiles\CMDCMDLINE\test.bat" "`

Comment: It still is not a definitive way to detect if the batch file was launched from the console or explorer.  I can execute a batch file just like I posted above from the cmd prompt and the `CMDCMDLINE` variable will look just like it does when launched from `EXPLORER`.

Comment: @Squashman Sure, but at the point when you're launching a batch file from CMD by manually typing `c:\...\cmd.exe /c ""c:\full\path\to\batch.bat" "`, you know what you're doing, and you're working against the system rather than with it

Comment: @GovindParmar, the system environment variable `%ComSpec%` should be the fully-qualified path to cmd.exe, at least since Vista. But I suppose an alternate command interpreter could replace the value. The Windows directory (i.e. "C:\Windows") is `%SystemRoot%`, so you can use "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe".

Answer (score 2):

Would you like get try this coding suggest doing this job...

Basically, use findstr to check the if the variable **`%cmdcmdline%`**  value match  this **`.cmd`** or **`.bat`**, if this return positively  then **`goto :eof`** (exit), but, if not, then **`run your code...`**

```bat
  @echo off & cd /d %~dp0" 

  echo/%cmdcmdline% | findstr /i "\.cmd \.bat" 2>nul && ( 

    title... by click.. & echo/%cmdcmdline% | findstr "%0" 

    echo/ bat: "%0" running by click

    timeout /t 5 /nobreak>nul & goto :eof

    ) || (

    title... by command line.. && echo/%cmdcmdline%| findstr "%0" 

    echo/ bat: "%0" running by command line 

    timeout /t 5 /nobreak>nul & goto :run_code

   )

  :run_code

  echo/ your code enter here

  ::  ....

  goto :eof
```

[image: 1st by click & 2nd by command line]